# Por que, dentro da função, o programa não está comparando de forma certa?

Tags: c

O programa recebe o numero de questões, o numero de alunos, cria um vetor do tipo char para o gabarito e compara com o resultado dos outros alunos,em uma matriz, mas dentro da função de `contagemvalores`, aparentemente a comparação não está sendo feita de forma correta.Qual poderia ser o problema?

A saída deveria ser quando eu uso a entrada:

```
5 3
ABCDE
AAABB
CBEDB
ABDDE
```

deveria dar:

```
2.00
4.00
8.00
```

E esta dando:

```
0.00
2.00
2.00
```

E quando coloco para printar a variável acerto que deveria ser 1, 2 e 4 , ela aparece como 0, 1 e 1.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** alocamatriz(int q, int a) //Declaracao da funcao de alocacao da matriz(notas dos alunos)
{
    int i;
    char** matriz = NULL;

    matriz = (char**) malloc(a * sizeof(char*));

    for(i = 0; i < a ; i++)
    {
        matriz[i] = (char*) malloc(q * sizeof(char));
    }

    return matriz;
}

void adicionavalores(char** matriz, int q, int a) //Declaracao da funcao que adiciona valores(questoes)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < q ; j++)
        {
            scanf("%c", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }

}

void contagemdevalores(char** matriz, char* gabarito, int q, int a) //Funcao que verifica igualdade com as questoes do aluno e com o gabarito
{
    int i, j, certo = 0;
    float media = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        certo = 0;

        for(j = 0; j < q; j++)
        {
            if(gabarito[j] == matriz[i][j])
                certo++;
        }

        media =(certo/q) * 10.0; //Media dos alunos
        printf("%.2f\n", media);

    }
}

char* adicionagabarito(int q)
{
    int i;
    char* gabarito = NULL;

    gabarito = (char*) malloc(q * sizeof(char));

    for(i = 0; i < q ; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &gabarito[i]);  
    }

    return gabarito;
}

int main (void)

{
    int alunos = 0,questoes = 0, i;
    char** matriz = NULL;
    char* gabarito = NULL;

    scanf("%d", &questoes);
    scanf("%d", &alunos);

    gabarito = adicionagabarito(questoes); //Chamada de funcao

    matriz = alocamatriz(questoes, alunos); //Chamada de funcao

    adicionavalores(matriz,questoes,alunos); //Chamada de funcao

    contagemdevalores(matriz, gabarito, questoes, alunos); //Chamada de funcao

    free(gabarito);
    free(matriz);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quando você colar um block de código numa pergunta, você pode selecionar o bloco e digitar Ctrl-K para formatá-lo como código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
media =(certo/q) * 10;
```

`certo` e `q` são inteiros, logo a divisão é feita nos inteiros: `1/3 == 0`.

(Sim, eu sei que você declarou `media` como float, mas o compilador não se importa — ele calcula **primeiro** o lado direito, e depois o esquerdo. Do lado direito, só tem operações de aritmética inteira.)

Tem várias formas de consertar isso:

```
media = 10.0f * certo / q
media = (certo / (float) q) * 10
media = ((float) certo / q) * 10
```

(a que eu prefiro, pessoalmente, é declarar `certo` como float, aí você não precisa ficar colocando as constantes em float ou meter conversão no meio do código)

Note que

```
media = certo / q * 10.0f
```

não funciona — multiplicação e divisão associam da esquerda para a direita, logo isso é equivalente a

```
media = (certo / q) * 10.0f
```

e quando o programa chega na multiplicação por 10 já é tarde demais.

---

Seu programa também tem outro problema. Quando você lê `scanf("%c", …)`, você lê o próximo caractere da entrada. Os formatos `%s`, `%d` e `%f` descartam caracteres em branco até acharem a próxima palavra ou número, mas `%c` não — se o próximo caractere for `' '` ou `'\n'`, o `scanf` lê o espaço em branco. Você pode verificar que esse é o caso fazendo a seguinte alteração:

```
 gabarito = adicionagabarito(questoes);
 printf("# %d\n", (int) gabarito[0]);  // imprime 10
```

Isso é fácil de resolver: é só você sempre lembrar de usar `" %c"` no lugar de `"%c"`.

Comment: Perfeito, esse eu consegui resolver, mas vc poderia me ajudar no porque a comparação entre os valores não estão batendo??

Comment: Pergunta editada, bom, dei o lugar de espaço antes mas não resolveu, eu deveria apenas fazer isso mesmo??

Comment: Sim, realmente deu certo, o único problema é que ao invés de 2.0, 4.0, 8.0, esta dando 2.0, 2.0, 4.0

Comment: Você tem certeza que você está rodando o seu programa com o arquivo de entrada certo? Seu código funciona perfeitamente aqui.

Comment: Esta atualizada, mas testei aqui o programa e ele rodou perfeitamente, acabaram os problemas, muito obrigado viu

Comment: Edita a sua questão de volta como ela estava (sem espaços antes dos `"%c"` e sem o `(float)`), pras próximas pessoas que acharem essa questão não ficarem perdidas procurando o problema do seu código.